# How would you define non-integer tetration?

Tags: tetration

Tetration is defined for all $n\in \Bbb{N}$ by 
$$
{^1}a = a \\
{^{n+1}}a = a^{\left({^n}a\right)}
$$
Thus ${^3}a$ means $a^{a^a}$.

Here $a$ could be any real (or indeed even complex) value, but only integer $n$ in the tetration is defined by this definition.

But I've seen questions here dealing with real valued tetration
(${^x}a$ for real $x$) and even one dealing with complex tetration
(${^z}a$ for complex $z$).

let's take one step at a time:  How does one define tetration with a rational hyperpower
$${^q}a : q \in \Bbb{Q}$$
(From there, the move to real tetration is the same sort of "easy" as defining real exponentiation.)

And what does ${^z}a$ mean for complex $z$?

Comment: Another good question, *why* would you define such a thing?

Comment: @bof: Lars Kindermann had written his thesis about the fractional iteration of the exponentiation in the context of an industrial process of producing sheets of steel in a set of consecutive steps by identical machines. However he approched/solved this using neural networks. *(The thesis (in German, having lots of interesting references) is online)*

Comment: @bof Fundamental physics makes use of exponentiation, determining whether the next arithmetic operator tetration has or doesn't have a role in fundamental physics is interesting.

Comment: You can take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/q/259278/9550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most intuitive construction for this is to have a infinitely-sized matrix ***A*** which performs 
$$ V(x) \cdot A  = V(a^x) \qquad \qquad \text{ where } V(x)=[1,x,x^2,x^3,...] $$
Such a matrix ***A*** is called "Carleman-matrix" (see wikipedia).
The idea is, that then
$$ V(x) \cdot A  = V(a^x) = V(\exp_a(x))\\
V(a^x) \cdot A  = V(a^{a^x}) = V(\exp_a^{[2]}(x)) \\
 \ldots $$
or 
$$ V(x) \cdot A^h = V(\exp_a^{[h]}(x)) $$
thus requiring the *h*'th power of the matrix $A$.
Approximations to this can be made by finite truncations of ***A*** - so let's in the following denote such finite truncations with the hat-symbol: $ \hat A$ .

It is so far not difficult to implement arbitrary precision to this if the base $a$ is in the range $\small 1 < a < \exp(\exp(-1))$ with finite matrices $\hat A$ - however, who needed such a construction for the integer height tetration?

But from here one idea is apparently straightforward: we need fractional powers of ***A*** to have fractional heights of tetration. For finite-size matrices one can define fractional powers using diagonalization and take the scalar elements of the diagonal matrix to the (fractional) *h*'th power. So finite truncations of ***A*** and its diagonalization gives an approximation.
Let the diagonalization of the truncated matrix $ A$ be written as 
$$\hat A = \hat M \cdot \hat D \cdot \hat M \, ^{-1}$$ and for notational convenience let's write $\small \hat W$ for $ \small \hat M \, ^{-1}$ 
then $$ \hat A^h  = \hat M \cdot \hat D \, ^h \cdot \hat W = \hat M \cdot \text{diag}( (d_{k,k})^h) \cdot \hat W $$ and -in principle-
$$ \hat V(x) \cdot \hat A \,^h \approx \hat V(\exp_a^{[h]}(x))$$
Unfortunately the truncation of $A$ spoils its Carleman-characteristic, and the best approximation is to use the second column only 
$$ \hat V(x) \cdot \hat M[,1] = \hat \sigma_a(x) \\
   \hat V(\hat \sigma_a(x)) \cdot \hat D \ ^h \cdot \hat W[,1] \approx \exp_a^{[h]}(x)$$

*See a worked example in Pari/GP [in my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/672543/1714) at the earlier question (your question here seems to get marked as a duplicate of that earlier one)*

---

Remark: the last procedere mimicks in principle the method of Ernst Schröder (the $ \hat \sigma _a(x)$ represents here the "Schröder-function") and can be accurate to the -in my opinion- currently best concept for the real tetration on the real axis by H. Kneser (implemented by members of the Tetrationforum) to *10* to *12* or more digits using matrix size of *32x32* . But even size *16x16* allows reasonable approximation to say *6* or *8* digits (don't know exactly from the top of my mind)
Another related concept, immediately implementable for bases *a* in the mentioned interval is to use Carleman-matrices for the $\exp_a()$-function but where the power series are recentered at an attractive fixpoint. Then the Carleman-matrices become triangular and diagonalization is simpler (and the results are slightly different). Also various other concepts have been discussed but are mostly far more complicated.